# How to find the index - in DATABASE table - of selected item in connected ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, combobox, sqldataadapter

Finding the selected item *string* in a combo box is easy:

```
String selectedString = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Finding the selected item *index* in a combo box is also easy:

```
int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
```

But finding the index **in a connected database table** of the selected item in the combo box doesn't seem so trivial:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblContacts ORDER BY colFirstname", sqlConnection);
    da.Fill(dt);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String addressRow = (String)dt.Rows[i]["colFirstname"];
        comboBox1.Items.Add(addressRow);
    }
```

I could try to somehow derive an index to the DB table from the selected item string, but that doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

What is the proper way of finding the index **in a connected database table** of the selected item in the combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combobox selected index is the index in DataTable.

Comment: That orderby is fired on database. So the data fetched is already sorted. Now that datatable is looped over to add data in combobox.

Comment: Gotcha! `int selectedIndexInTable = (int)dt.Rows[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]["colId"];` Thanks +1.

Comment: This assumes, of course, that there is an INT IDENTITY column for the table.